# dropdown box(sharepoint form field) validation sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form, validation, dropdown

I have a sharepoint form field(look up field), a dropdown box in a list...below is the screen shot[image]
when i type into it it finds the name..

[image]
but when i type a text which is not present in the drop down box it still accepts it

[image]

in firefox this dropdown box, does not allow to type in ..we are only using IE .. and our clients like the way that the drop down box allows u to type in to find the names...is there any way that i can incorporate a validation in it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should disable users to add unique values.

Go to your List > Settings > Column > Enforce Unique Values. See the screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NkId.png